# XmlDocument not available in Visual Studio 2012 DLL build

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012, dll

Using visual Studio 2012, creating a Portable Class Library project, I would like to use the [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class .
However the library is not being found, even with

```
using System.Xml;
```

The error message is:

```
"are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference"
```

If I right click on References -> "Add References", browse to the dll directory (address below), and select the following dll:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.XML.dll
```

Then click OK, an error appears

```
"A reference to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.XML.dll' could not be added. 
This component is already automatically referenced by the build system."
```

So a work around is to use an open source XML parsing library. Any suggestions ? Xerces ?

But it would be preferable to use the built in C# XmlDocument class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `XmlDocument` is not available on all frameworks, hence may not be available in a PCL (depending on what framework options you have selected). However, the newer [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) generally *is* - try adding a reference to `System.Xml.Linq.dll` if necessary.

The entire point of a PCL is that it restricts you to the strict subset of components available on all of the selected frameworks.

Comment: thanks for the reply.I had selected the ".Net Framework 4.5" and ".Net for Windows Store Apps" target frame works in order to retain the widest range of references. I already tried the other System.XML.*.dll libraries with the same errors generated.

Comment: @NickT right; and `XmlDocument` does not exist in netcore (aka ".Net for Windows Store Apps"), so you **can't use `XmlDocument` here**. You *can*, however, use `XDocument` - see here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bN5N3.png (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx))

Comment: @MarcGravell Is there any way to bolt an extra API (e.g. XmlDocument), which you know that all your targets will support, on to a PCL profile?